# How to replace screen.width value with my own defined value?

Tags: javascript, html

How to replace screen.width value with my own defined value?

I want to define a fake `screen.width`:

```
var screen.width = 1024;
```

in `<head>`

So that when the below code loads it will always display = `<h1>test 2</h1>` in any `screen.width`

I am using the following the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (screen.width>=1400)
{
    document.write('<h1>test 1</h1>');
}else 

{
    document.write('<h1>test 2</h1>');
}
</script>
```

Hope I am clear to explain my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, you could make `screen`'s properties mutable like this:

```
var tempScreen = {};
for (var obj in screen)
  tempScreen[obj] = screen[obj];

tempScreen.__proto__ = screen.__proto__;
screen = tempScreen;

screen.width = 400;
console.log(screen.width);  // -> 400
```

Comment: This is a great trick and I've used to it fake screen sizes for unit testing, however, it doesn't work in IE9 or Firefox :(